How to establish a ssh connnection to a windows ssh server from windows computer using a private key and public key generated with "ssh-keygen"
I am trying to connect to a Windows SSH server from another Windows computer. I generated public and private RSA keys using the command "ssh-keygen," and I added a passphrase to them. I copied the content of the public key and added it to the "authorized_keys" file.
It is the only text in that file. It took the private key and put it into the other computer. When I executed "ssh -i file.key username@ip" in the .ssh folder I connected successfully. Before I connected, ssh asked for the password of the account that I want to connect to and I wrote it.
After that, I could connect without the key with the command "ssh username@ip". It asked for the user password and I connected.
I want to connect with the user password and the key (the server demands both the user password and the key to connect). So I changed the following things in the "sshd_config" file in "C:\ProgramData\ssh":
PubkeyAuthentication yes
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no

But when I try to connect to the computer with the command "ssh username@ip" or "ssh -i file.key username@ip" ssh always says "username@ip Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).". Can you please help fix this problem?
I transferred the private key to a flash drive.
This is ACL on the client computer:



This is ACL for the public key on the Windows SSH server:



This the "sshd_config":
# This is the sshd server system-wide configuration file.  See
# sshd_config(5) for more information.

# The strategy used for options in the default sshd_config shipped with
# OpenSSH is to specify options with their default value where
# possible, but leave them commented.  Uncommented options override the
# default value.

#Port 22
#AddressFamily any
#ListenAddress 0.0.0.0
#ListenAddress ::

#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_rsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_dsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ecdsa_key
#HostKey __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/ssh_host_ed25519_key

# Ciphers and keying
#RekeyLimit default none

# Logging
SyslogFacility AUTH
LogLevel VERBOSE

# Authentication:

#LoginGraceTime 2m
#PermitRootLogin prohibit-password
#StrictModes yes
#MaxAuthTries 6
#MaxSessions 10

PubkeyAuthentication yes

# The default is to check both .ssh/authorized_keys and .ssh/authorized_keys2
# but this is overridden so installations will only check .ssh/authorized_keys
AuthorizedKeysFile  .ssh/authorized_keys

#AuthorizedPrincipalsFile none

# For this to work you will also need host keys in %programData%/ssh/ssh_known_hosts
#HostbasedAuthentication no
# Change to yes if you don't trust ~/.ssh/known_hosts for
# HostbasedAuthentication
#IgnoreUserKnownHosts no
# Don't read the user's ~/.rhosts and ~/.shosts files
#IgnoreRhosts yes

# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication no
PermitEmptyPasswords no


# GSSAPI options
#GSSAPIAuthentication no

#AllowAgentForwarding yes
#AllowTcpForwarding yes
#GatewayPorts no
#PermitTTY yes
#PrintMotd yes
#PrintLastLog yes
#TCPKeepAlive yes
#UseLogin no
#PermitUserEnvironment no
#ClientAliveInterval 0
#ClientAliveCountMax 3
#UseDNS no
#PidFile /var/run/sshd.pid
#MaxStartups 10:30:100
#PermitTunnel no
#ChrootDirectory none
#VersionAddendum none

# no default banner path
#Banner none

# override default of no subsystems
Subsystem   sftp    sftp-server.exe

# Example of overriding settings on a per-user basis
#Match User anoncvs
#   AllowTcpForwarding no
#   PermitTTY no
#   ForceCommand cvs server

Match Group administrators
       AuthorizedKeysFile __PROGRAMDATA__/ssh/administrators_authorized_keys

These are the logs on the client computer;
OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/user/.ssh/config error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_config error:2
debug2: resolve_canonicalize: hostname hostip is address
debug2: ssh_connect_direct
debug1: Connecting to hostip [hostip] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/user/.ssh/pineap.key.pub error:2
debug1: identity file pineap.key type -1
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/user/.ssh/pineap.key-cert error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/user/.ssh/pineap.key-cert.pub error:2
debug1: identity file pineap.key-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to hostip:22 as 'username'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from hostip
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com
debug2: languages ctos:
debug2: languages stoc:
debug2: first_kex_follows 0
debug2: reserved 0
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:<numbersandletters>
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from hostip
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/Users/user/.ssh/known_hosts2 error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts error:2
debug3: Failed to open file:C:/ProgramData/ssh/ssh_known_hosts2 error:2
debug1: Host 'hostip' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in C:\\Users\\user/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks
debug3: unable to connect to pipe \\\\.\\pipe\\openssh-ssh-agent, error: 2
debug1: pubkey_prepare: ssh_get_authentication_socket: No such file or directory
debug1: Will attempt key: pineap.key  explicit
debug2: pubkey_prepare: done
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 7
debug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received
debug1: kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521>
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: preferred publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: pineap.key
debug3: failed to open file:C:/dev/tty error:3
debug1: read_passphrase: can't open /dev/tty: No such file or directory
Enter passphrase for key 'pineap.key':
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:K3E/rUpXjlUKHlcnfr2/cY8u/r33ekATfpbEaY8Qjfg
debug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug3: authmethod_lookup keyboard-interactive
debug3: remaining preferred: password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
debug2: userauth_kbdint
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug2: we sent a keyboard-interactive packet, wait for reply
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug3: userauth_kbdint: disable: no info_req_seen
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
username@hostip: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).

These are the server logs:
Level   Date and Time   Source  Event ID    Task Category
Information 7/6/2024 5:23:00 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 50504 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 5:23:00 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Failed publickey for useernamehostcomputer from clientip port 50504 ssh2: RSA SHA256:<numbersandletters>
Information 7/6/2024 5:23:00 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Authentication refused.
Information 7/6/2024 5:22:44 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection from clientip port 50504 on clientip port 22
Information 7/6/2024 5:22:01 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 5:22:01 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on :: port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 3:28:03 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 50440 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 3:28:03 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Authentication refused.
Information 7/6/2024 3:07:13 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 50421 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 3:07:13 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Authentication refused.
Information 7/6/2024 3:06:20 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 50419 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 3:06:04 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 50418 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 3:02:37 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 50412 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 3:02:37 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Authentication refused.
Information 7/6/2024 2:58:13 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 50394 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 2:58:13 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Authentication refused.
Information 7/6/2024 2:55:58 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 50392 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 2:55:58 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Authentication refused.
Information 7/6/2024 2:44:36 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 50322 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 2:44:36 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Authentication refused.
Information 7/6/2024 2:44:27 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 50321 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 2:44:10 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 2:44:10 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on :: port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 2:07:55 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 50289 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 2:07:55 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Authentication refused.
Information 7/6/2024 2:06:57 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 2:06:57 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on :: port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 2:04:44 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 2:04:44 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on :: port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 1:45:40 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 49974 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 1:45:40 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Authentication refused.
Information 7/6/2024 1:45:33 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: reprocess config line 34: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Information 7/6/2024 1:45:33 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: rexec line 34: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Information 7/6/2024 1:45:17 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 1:45:17 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on :: port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 1:36:27 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 49969 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 1:36:27 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Authentication refused.
Information 7/6/2024 1:36:20 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: reprocess config line 34: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Information 7/6/2024 1:36:20 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: rexec line 34: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Information 7/6/2024 1:34:34 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 1:34:34 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on :: port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 1:26:21 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Received signal 8; terminating.
Information 7/6/2024 1:25:07 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 49959 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 1:25:07 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Authentication refused.
Information 7/6/2024 1:25:00 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: reprocess config line 34: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Information 7/6/2024 1:24:59 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: rexec line 34: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Information 7/6/2024 1:24:58 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 49958 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 1:24:49 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: reprocess config line 34: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Information 7/6/2024 1:24:48 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: rexec line 34: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Information 7/6/2024 1:24:46 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 49957 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 1:24:46 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Authentication refused.
Information 7/6/2024 1:24:40 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: reprocess config line 34: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Information 7/6/2024 1:24:39 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: rexec line 34: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Information 7/6/2024 1:24:27 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 49956 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 1:24:27 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: reprocess config line 34: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Information 7/6/2024 1:24:27 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: rexec line 34: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Information 7/6/2024 1:24:11 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 1:24:11 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on :: port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 1:11:42 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 49779 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 1:11:40 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: reprocess config line 34: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Information 7/6/2024 1:11:40 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: rexec line 34: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Information 7/6/2024 1:11:33 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Accepted password for useernamehostcomputer from clientip port 49778 ssh2
Information 7/6/2024 1:11:27 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Authentication refused.
Information 7/6/2024 1:11:18 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: reprocess config line 34: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Information 7/6/2024 1:11:18 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: rexec line 34: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Information 7/6/2024 1:10:54 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 1:10:54 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on :: port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 1:03:02 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 49712 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 1:03:02 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Authentication refused.
Information 7/6/2024 1:03:02 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: reprocess config line 34: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Information 7/6/2024 1:03:02 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: rexec line 34: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Information 7/6/2024 1:01:18 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 1:01:18 AM OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on :: port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 12:50:19 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 59566 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 12:50:19 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Authentication refused.
Information 7/6/2024 12:50:19 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: reprocess config line 34: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Information 7/6/2024 12:50:19 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: rexec line 34: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Information 7/6/2024 12:49:38 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 59559 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 12:49:38 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Authentication refused.
Information 7/6/2024 12:49:38 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: reprocess config line 34: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Information 7/6/2024 12:49:38 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: rexec line 34: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Information 7/6/2024 12:46:02 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 59501 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 12:46:02 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Authentication refused.
Information 7/6/2024 12:46:02 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: reprocess config line 34: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Information 7/6/2024 12:46:02 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: rexec line 34: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Information 7/6/2024 12:44:02 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 59369 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 12:44:02 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Authentication refused.
Information 7/6/2024 12:44:02 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: reprocess config line 34: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Information 7/6/2024 12:44:01 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: rexec line 34: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Information 7/6/2024 12:41:41 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 59326 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 12:41:41 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Authentication refused.
Information 7/6/2024 12:41:41 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: reprocess config line 34: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Information 7/6/2024 12:41:40 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: rexec line 34: Deprecated option RSAAuthentication
Information 7/6/2024 12:41:24 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 12:41:24 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on :: port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 12:36:42 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 59125 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 12:36:42 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Authentication refused.
Information 7/6/2024 12:33:16 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 59097 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 12:33:16 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Authentication refused.
Information 7/6/2024 12:31:21 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 59009 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 12:31:21 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Authentication refused.
Information 7/6/2024 12:31:12 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 59008 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 12:29:23 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 12:29:23 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on :: port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 12:27:28 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 12:27:28 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on :: port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 12:22:01 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 58953 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 12:19:41 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Accepted password for useernamehostcomputer from clientip port 58948 ssh2
Information 7/6/2024 12:18:02 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 12:18:02 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on :: port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 12:12:40 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 58926 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 12:12:40 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Authentication refused.
Information 7/6/2024 12:12:36 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 58925 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 12:12:02 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 12:12:02 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on :: port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 12:10:12 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 12:10:12 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on :: port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 12:06:28 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Accepted password for useernamehostcomputer from clientip port 58823 ssh2
Information 7/6/2024 12:06:13 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Accepted password for useernamehostcomputer from clientip port 58822 ssh2
Information 7/6/2024 12:06:05 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Authentication refused.
Information 7/6/2024 12:05:49 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 12:05:49 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on :: port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 12:04:28 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 58820 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 12:04:28 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Authentication refused.
Information 7/6/2024 12:04:02 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 58819 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 12:04:01 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Authentication refused.
Information 7/6/2024 12:03:49 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Connection reset by authenticating user useernamehostcomputer clientip port 58818 [preauth]
Information 7/6/2024 12:01:56 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
Information 7/6/2024 12:01:56 AM    OpenSSH 4   None    sshd: Server listening on :: port 22.

The problem is that I could connect with just "ssh username@ip" without the key. So I made these changes:
PubkeyAuthentication yes 
PasswordAuthentication no 
PermitEmptyPasswords no

But after that I couldn't connect to the server and this appears message "username@hostip: Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive)." when I try to log in any way.

You can’t use password and key authentication, you am can have them both enabled, but you can’t require both a password and the key. You will want to post the verbose logs from both the client and server and of course your OpenSSH configuration file. You will also want to work on the clarity of your description of the problem. You should also submit screenshots of the ACL for the key on the client and server.

To piggy-back on @Ramhound's comment, the encryption passphrase of the SSH key effectively acts the way you want the user passphrase to work in this scenario- SSH passphrases should be secure and since they shouldn't be shared, if User A's SSH key is added to User A's account, and User A's SSH key is encrypted with a passphrase, it's an almost surety User A is User A since this is effectively more secure than logging in to a user account with a passphrase only.

@Ramhound No, they added that ability to OpenSSH v6.2 in 2012 (as AuthenticationMethods).

@grawity_u1686 - Requiring both a password and key authentication or a password to authenticate to the key.  I see that it has two different interpretations of the author's question. What is that authentication method called exactly?

@Jeff123 - The permissions on the keys are incorrect. They must be accessible only by the user who will use them.  Furthermore, it seems you attempted to connect on port 58926 but your server is clearly configured on port 22. Your server is also having problems loading the configuration file, and even if that wasn't the case, you disabled password authentication and only allow key authetication.

Hello, there are two user profiles on the server (I didn't mention that, because I didn’t think of it) . I disabled the second user's permissions to read and write in the ".ssh" folder, so only the user that I am trying to connect to has the rights to that folder. When I tried to connect without the key  ssh didn’t allow it. As a result of the changes made when I tried to connect with the key I connected successfully. As of the comments for the password I meant not the password to authenticate the key, but the windows account ‘s password. Thanks a lot for the help and quick responses.

@Ramhound: It's not a method but the ability to require more than one method. You're misinterpreting the logs; they show the client port number, not the server port.

@Jeff123 - If my comment answered your question, I will take the time, to find a duplicate to this question

Everything works as I intended and I appreciate your efforts a lot. I apologize if there was any misunderstanding. Thanks for your time. I will rely on your continued support in the future.
